# MySQL: select emails from one table only if not in another table?

Tags: mysql

I am going to build a table called donotemail that will contain the email addresses of people who ask to be removed from our email list. I have another table called users with an email column. How can I select all the emails from users but only if the email address is not in the donotemail table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT Email.address
FROM Email LEFT OUTER JOIN DoNotMail on Email.address = DoNotMail.address
WHERE DoNotMail.address is null
```

It avoids needing a subquery.

Comment: Ha, I was just writing a similar query when I saw a new answer had been posted.  Good thing I checked before submitting.

Comment: Did seem to be a flood of answers - the four before me were all posted while I wrote my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 select u.email from users u where u.email not in (select email from donotemail)
```

OR

<strike>select u.email from users u inner join donotemail d on u.email != d.email</strike>

**EDIT: The join doesn't work**

Comment: "inner join donotemail d on u.email != d.email" ?? you'll join on every other user won't you ?

Comment: yeah, but that will be a null set since donoteamail should have email as its primary key

Comment: what ? u = [a@example.com, b@exemple.com, c@exemple.com], donotemail = [a, b] => inner join on different = [a/b, b/a, c/a, c/b] no ?

Comment: Byron:  Er... are you sure?  If email is primary key in both tables, u.email != d.email will be true for n or n-1 rows in the second table, where n is the number of rows in the second table.

Comment: @Streetpc yes, I think you're right, I was struggling to wrap my mind around what was wrong with this. I think you will get u x d-1 results, which isn't exactly what you want

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT email
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM no_mail_users nmu
    WHERE nmu.id = u.id
)
```

Comment: correlated subqueries are extremely, EXTREMELY slow, as you end up having one query per row in the outer table.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add another column to your email table, labeled Active, when set to 1 it is currently emailing, and when set to 0 it no longer emails, then you can just select and filter based on that switch?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
select email from users where email not in (select email from donotemail)
```

Comment: A join is way faster than a sub-select

Comment: if you have a NULL email in donotemail, it will return an empty set

Comment: @artemb it depends, subselect can be executed only once if the query optimizer understands that it should not be refetched

Comment: @streetpc: According to the MySQL manual, IN subqueries are converted to correlated subqueries: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html