# Select users from one table only if not in another

Tags: mysql

We have two tables:

-- users --

```
id  name    borrower
--  ------  --------
1   Peter   1
2   John    1
3   Mark    1
4   David   0
```

-- lendings --

```
id  from  to  amount
--  ----  --  ------
1   1     2   100
```

I need to output users that Peter hasn't lent any money and that are borrowers=1 (excluding Peter from the results), like this:

```
id  name    borrower
--  ------  --------
3   Mark    1
```

Right now I am stuck with this query (doesn't work):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `lendings` l
ON u.`id` = l.`from`
WHERE l.`from` is null
AND u.`id` != 1
AND u.`borrower` = 1
```

*This is a simplified example of the actual code to keep the question useful/readable for future readers.*

Related question: [MySQL: select emails from one table only if not in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002728/mysql-select-emails-from-one-table-only-if-not-in-another-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    users
WHERE
    id NOT IN (SELECT 
            id
        FROM
            lendings)
        AND borrower = 1;
```

You might want to use different column names as I believe from and to are reserved words in mysql.

Comment: The error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" was appearing, I've edited your query and it works great now. Great stuff Lazerblade, thanks!