# query to show items that are NOT in the list

Tags: mysql, sql

This query returns me the list of room #077 that is occupied on specific day; how do I reverse this query and show only times that are NOT in the database between 07:00:00 and 22:00:00? (30 minutes intervals) and each class should take only 1 hour and 30 minutes

```
select 
    *
from
    (select 
        rooms.id, rooms.number, rooms.building, rooms.capacity
    from
        rooms) R1,
    (select 
        exam_schedules.room_id,
            exam_schedules.day,
            exam_schedules.start_time,
            exam_schedules.end_time
    from
        exam_schedules) R2
where
    R2.room_id = R1.id and R2.day = 'tuesday' and R1.number = '077'
```

This is the result:

```
ID  number  Bulding Capacity    room_id day start_time  end_time
1   077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 10:30:00    12:00:00
```

But I need the result that is shown below (which is pretty much shows the AVAILABLE times that are NOT occupied by exams AND could no be occupied by other exam since it might cause scheduling issues: for example if exam is already scheduled at 10.30, only 9.00 (not 9.30) should be shown since if 9.30 is shown - it will cause the conflict: 9.30+1.30 = 11.00 - but I already have the 10.30-12.00 scheduled for this room)

```
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 07:00:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 07:30:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 08:00:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 08:30:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 09:00:00
//note that time frame from 9.30-10.30 is not available since there is a class at 10.30 scheduled already
//note that time period 10.30-<12.00 not shown since class is already scheduled for this timeframe 10.30-12.00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 12:00:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 12:30:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 13:00:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 13:30:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 14:00:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 14:30:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 15:00:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 15:30:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 16:00:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 16:30:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 17:00:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 17:30:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 18:00:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 18:30:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 19:00:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 19:30:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 20:00:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 20:30:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 21:00:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 21:30:00
 1  077 ACT 12  1   tuesday 22:00:00
```

The table with all possible timeframes does not exist in the database. Can I maybe hadcode it into the query?

Comment: I suppose you are looking `times that are in the database NOT between 07:00:00 and 22:00:00` rather than for values that aren't in the database... (good luck finding those...)

Comment: can I create some sort of array that is hardcoded into the query? I am prtty new to this, therefore I created the query, but need to "reverse it"

Comment: As Mosty Mostacho says, this needs more explanation. I made that suggestion before looking clearly at the query, but now that I did, it turns out that that explanation makes no sense...

Comment: Andrew, try to follow a format like in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255266), providing current data, the result and also explaining how to get to that data.

Comment: Got it. The question is: Do you have any table that has all combinations for each day an half-hour?

Comment: No, I don't; will it help to make it? Can I just hardcode it into some sort of array directly into the query?

Comment: Is this code used in PHP? I mean, since you don't have any table to get all the available combinations from, it would be more intuitive to get all the occupied time slots and just show the rest in your code.

Comment: Extremely bad news for you :( Generating data is something that should be done at an application level. If you insist on doing this on the DB, then this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034668) might be useful.

Comment: @Andrew: you'll find a table of intervals very useful, it will allow you to use JOINS.

Comment: I ended up creating such table; I will try it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the list of all possible values.  You can do this with a query like:
    select *
    from (select '2012-01-01 7:00:00' from dual union all
          select '2012-01-01 7:30:00' from dual union all . . .
         ) times

That is, you can use union all to put the data together.  I find it easiest to use Excel to put together the SQL statements needed to make this work.

That said, a calendar/calendar-time table is something you should consider.  Having a table with each possible time slot it in will probably help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Year='1965'
```

this sql query will return a data set containing all the rows from the 'Persons' table where all the 'Year' fields equal to '1965'. As you said, you wanted to reverse your sql query so it returns the opposite data set. This is made possible in the WHERE clause, where you can use the not equal to operator: <> or != in some versions of SQL

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Year<>'1965'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Year!='1965'
```

will return a data set containing rows from the 'Persons' table where its field does not equal to '1965'.

Hope this helps in your sql query. you simply need to implement the <> or != operator where needed to return the opposite data set from your database this is assuming you wanted the opposite data from the data you're already having returned with your current query.

If this is not what you wanted please update your question so that you clearly explain what output you expect it to have - an example - so that a query can be made to retrieve the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you what I think is the answer first: 

I think what you are looking for is `Between ... And...`. Or better to say `Not(Between .. And..)`. `Between ... And...` is a range operator. So  `x Between 1 And 10 = 1<x<10` and `Not x Between 1 And 10 = x<1 || x>10`.
There are certain part of the query that are plain wrong to me:

Why do you have the `select *` anyway? You could just join the to tables like:

```
select 
    rooms.id, rooms.number, rooms.building, rooms.capacity,exam_schedules.room_id,
        exam_schedules.day,
        exam_schedules.start_time,
        exam_schedules.end_time
from
    rooms,exam_schedules
where
    exam_schedules.room_id = rooms.id and exam_schedules.day = 'tuesday' and rooms.number = '077'
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally do this with a left join and include only rows that are not in the right table.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (select 
        rooms.id, rooms.number, rooms.building, rooms.capacity
    from
        rooms) R1
LEFT JOIN (select 
        exam_schedules.room_id,
            exam_schedules.day,
            exam_schedules.start_time,
            exam_schedules.end_time
    from
        exam_schedules) R2
ON
    R2.room_id = R1.id and R2.day = R1.day and (R2.start BETWEEN R1.start AND R1.end OR R2.end BETWEEN R1.start AND R1.end OR R1.start BETWEEN R2.start AND R2.end OR R1.end BETWEEN R2.start AND R2.end)
WHERE R2.room_id IS NULL;
```